# MVC - The model item passed into the dictionary is of type.. but this dictionary requires a model item of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I cannot understand why I have this error because what I'm trying to do should be fairly simple:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Interface.Models.UserAccount]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Interface.Models.UserAccount'.

Index.cshtml

```
@model Interface.Models.UserAccount

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>Register</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Create an Account</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

HomeController.cs

```
namespace Interface.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Account
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        SqlConnection con = new      SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString);
            MyDB db = new MyDB();
            {
            return View(db.userAccount.ToList());
            }
         }
         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Index(UserAccount account)
         {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MyDB db = new MyDB();
            {
                db.userAccount.Add(account);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            ViewBag.Message = account.FirstName + " " + account.LastName + "successfully registered.";
        }
        return View();
    }
```

The original /Home/Index page was redundant for my application, so what I was trying to do was replace /Account/Register so that /Account/Register is actually just /Home/Index.

The problem lies where it is returning items which were part of a view before, and it doesn't like it.

How can I amend so that this page loads correctly? I see a lot of similar results, but they have IEnumerable within their code when I don't

Comment: The message is self explanatory. You view has `@model UserAccount` (a single object), but you controller method is returning a collection of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass list of user accounts instead of single user account
You should pass only one user account, for example:

```
db.userAccount.ToList().First()
```